# AngularJS Custom Directive shows {{obj}} but not {{obj.prop}}?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I'm trying to build a very simple Angular directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        template: "{{result}} {{result.startTime}}",
        scope: {
            result: '@result'
        }
    };
});
```

And I use it this way in the view:

```
<div my-directive result="{{result}}"></div>
```

the problem is that `{{result}}` is displayed correctly (as a json) abject, while `{{result.startTime}}` is not displayed, despite the fact that the displayed `{{result}}` contains the `startTime` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems:

1 You need to pass the model in, not the interpolated string.

```
<div my-directive result="result"></div>
```

2 You need to assign the value to the directive, so use '=' instead of '@' which gives you the 1-way binding from the directive back to DOM only.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        template: "{{result}}, {{result.startTime}}",
        scope: {
            result: '='
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj7md/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you bro :)
I get this error : http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse:syntax?p0=result&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Bresult%7D%7D&p4=result%7D%7D

Comment: @Hasan I added a working demo for you. Did you fix the template?

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        template: "{{result}} {{result.startTime}}",
        scope: {
            result: '='
        }
    };
});
```

You're using the wrong isolate scope symbol there I believe, @ will give you the string representation of the variable passed in = will two way bind, if the name is the same as the property you can leave it out and just use = as shown above.

Comment: Thank you bro :)
I get this error : http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse:syntax?p0=result&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Bresult%7D%7D&p4=result%7D%7D

Comment: No problem glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the "=" rather than the "@". The "@" brings it in as a string reference.

```
scope: {
  result: "="
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro :)
I get this error : http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse:syntax?p0=result&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Bresult%7D%7D&p4=result%7D%7D